# Is there anyway to disable module validation of ioncube_loader for development work on a local?

Tags: magento-1.8, module, validation, ioncube

I have a client who uses the ioncube_loader, but I can't get it working on a local version because of the validation of my domain. I have downloaded the apache module and that is working, it just the callback that fails to allow the page to render properly.

Am I able to disable the validation so I can do my updates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to contact the great people at Ioncube and they were able to update the license with updated url's. I installed it an worked perfectly.